# Rotate Sine Wave Equation by $69^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

I want to rotate a sine wave equation of:

$$\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{4\pi}$$

by $21^\circ$ counterclockwise (so the positive $x-$ axis is not at $90^\circ$ bearing but rather $69^\circ$ bearing)

Answer (score 2):

Every point on your sine-curve can be expressed as 
$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}x\\\frac{\sin\left(\pi x\right)}{4\pi}\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb R^2$$

Now [rotate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) this vector by 21 degrees you will get

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos 21° & \sin21°\\-\sin21°&\cos21°\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\\frac{\sin\left(\pi x\right)}{4\pi}\end{pmatrix}$$