# What is the $3$D equation for a damped sine wave?

Tags: trigonometry, wave-equation

[This](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damped_sine_wave) is the equation for a $2$D damped sine wave, what is the $3$D equivalent?

For reference, a $2$D sine wave would be of form $y=\sin x$, and a 3D sine wave would be of form $z=\sin(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$.

Comment: I think there may be more context required.  How is the wave three-dimensional?  What requirements does it meet?

Comment: @abiessu edited

Comment: I see your edit, and now my question is, do you just want an essentially two-dimensional equation rotated/scaled into a three-dimensional coordinate system?  If so, consider the answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/686879/86846

Comment: Taking the reference you gave and the comparison equations, I would guess that you are looking for something along the lines of $$z=e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\sin(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$$ but note that this expects that you are supplying $(x,y)$ coordinates along the line $y=x$.

Comment: @abiessu while I do believe that would work for a general purpose, I’m asking this question in context of a 3D visualization I’m working on, and I’m not sure that the plotting library I’m using would be able to handle that. I think a function is required.

Comment: If you want to apply damping in a circular pattern around a central point, you should be able to use that equation directly.  If you follow any particular line away from $(x,y)=(0,0)$ you should see the same damping pattern.

Comment: @abiessu previous comment was in reference to your 2nd comment. The equation you provided works, thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As in the comments, the equation

$$z=e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\sin(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$$
or else phase-shifted and scaled as
$$z=e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\cos(2\pi\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$$

expresses damping along any ray $ax+by=0$ extending from the origin, and this was achieved by substitution of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ in place of $t$ in the Wikipedia listing at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damped_sine_wave.